# PYTHON Why is my if statement always returning false

Tags: python, if-statement

I am new to python and trying to write a program that requires the user to guess a number, 1 - 6 and then they are told if they guessed right or not. However, even when the user guesses right the else statement is still returned.

I apologise for the beginner question, although this really has me stuck because the 'guess' variable is being assigned correctly, I tested this by moving the `print("Your guess was: ",guess)` outside of the function and executed after the function was called which always returned with the same value that the user inputs.

```
#Function to take guess
def userGuess (guess):
    guess = input("Take a guess.\n")
    print("Your guess was: ",guess)
    return guess

#Define Variables
diceNum = random.randint(1,6)
guess = 0

#Call Function
guess = userGuess(guess)

#Check answer
if guess == diceNum:
    print("You guessed right!, the number was: ",diceNum)
else:
    print("You did not guess it right, the number was: ",diceNum)
```

Comment: `guess` is a string. `diceNum` is an int. Convert one or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the user input to an integer prior to comparing:

```
guess = int(input("Take a guess.\n"))
```

If you want an explanation as to *why* your if statement returned `false` for a comparison between an integer and a string, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40403108/how-can-python-compare-strings-with-integers).