# Calling functions based on a if condition in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

i have to call the main function based on the number of arguments passed. When i call the script the functions are not working.

Sample Code:

```
    def func1():
      somecode
    def func2():
      somecode
    def func3():
      somecode
    def main():
      if len(sys.argv) == "5":
        func1()
        func3()
      elif len(sys.argv) == "8":
       func2()
       func3()
    if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

Comment: What is your question? On a side note, one obvious problem: don't compare strings ("5") and integers (len(...)).

Comment: What's the question? Also, please reformat the sample code.

Comment: when i call the script, the func1 and func2 and func3 are not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40403108/how-can-python-compare-strings-with-integers

Comment: `5 != "5"`, as mentioned, use `if len(sys.argv) == 5:` and `elif len(sys.argv) == 8:` to correctly compare the number of arguments passed.

Comment: thank you mkrieger. It worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can Python compare strings with integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40403108/how-can-python-compare-strings-with-integers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are comparing `len(sys.argv)` with a string:

```
  if len(sys.argv) == "5":
    func1()
    func3()
  elif len(sys.argv) == "8":
   func2()
   func3()
```

changing to

```
  if len(sys.argv) == 5:
    func1()
    func3()
  elif len(sys.argv) == 8:
   func2()
   func3()
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not calling those functions because this `if`-test:

```
if len(sys.argv) == "5":
```

is always False. The function `len()` returns an integer and an integer in Python is never equal to a string. Do this instead:

```
if len(sys.argv) == 5:
```