# Simple Guessing Game in Python that doesn't work

Tags: python

I am trying to make a simple guessing game. When I run the code and print the number in advance to check if the program is working, it keeps on having the same wrong response. In other words, even if the guess variable is equal to the `num` variable, the program still returns "Incorrect!", and I can't figure out why. Thank you in advance. The code is pretty self-explanatory, so I'll post it here.

```
import random

num = random.randint(1, 6)
print(num)

guess = input(f'Guess a number: ')

if guess == num:
    print(f'Correct!')
else:
    print(f'Incorrect!')
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I meant "figure out".

Comment: The `guess` you are reading from the user is a string. The `num` you are getting from the randint  is an integer. You should covert the `guess` to an integer before comparing, like this: `if int(guess) == num:` ...

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: mark it as "solved" by clicking the "tick" near the answer.Welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing different types. `num` is an integer number while the `guess` is a string. You need to convert it to an integer before comparing them.

Try using `num == int(guess)` instead.

Comment: There have got to be a million duplicates for this question, but the SO search is failing me.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - similar, but not an exact dupe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661829/how-to-compare-string-and-integer-in-python

Comment: @KarlKnechtel there is also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - this is also related, but asks "how it does that" not "why it doesn't work", although, i guess, the initial question in his head was the same - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40403108/how-can-python-compare-strings-with-integers